# AngularJS router config is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm just started to learn angular JS.
I made some test code for routing.
But it seems not working

demoApp.js

```
var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp',[])

demoApp.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when('/view1',
            {   
                controller:'SimpleController'
                ,templateUrl : 'View1.html'
            })
        .when('/view2',
            {
                controller:'SimpleController'
                ,templateUrl : 'View2.html'
            })
        .otherwise({redirectTo:'/view1'});  

});

demoApp.controller('SimpleController',function($scope){
        $scope.customers = [
                {name:'Terry.Cho',city:'Seoul'},
                {name:'Cath',city:'Suwon'},
                {name:'Carry',city:'Suwon'}
        ];
        alert('hello controller');
    } );


alert("hello");
```

home.html

```
<html ng-app="demoApp">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=EUC-KR">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="demoApp.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#/view1">View1</a>
    <a href="#/view2">View2</a>

    <div>
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

view1.html

```
<div class="container">
    <h2> View 1 </h2>
```

view2.html

```
<div class="container">
    <h2> View 2 </h2>
```

did i missing something in demoApp.config or controller setting?
i also got error message in javascript console

Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.9/$injector/modulerr?p0=demoApp&p1=Error%3A…ogleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.9%2Fangular.min.js%3A32%3A232)

Comment: have you referenced `angular.route.min.js` because its shifted to its own separated file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the [ngRoute](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute) module. You have to add `angular-route.js` file to your scripts and load the module like this:

```
 angular.module('demoApp', ['ngRoute']);
```

Answer (score 2):

added demo.js

```
var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp',['ngRoute'])
```

and added in home.html

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular-route.min.js
```

Answer (score 0):

according you your `HTML` you are missing a reference to `ngRoute`  module to your application module. like below

```
var demo = angular.module('demoapp',['ngRoute']);
```